# Reproducible weight matrix tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I would like to reproduce twice the same results of a training in terms of weight matrices.

I already have my validation set fixed (not split during the training):

```
normed_x_train, normed_x_test, y_train, y_test = 
        train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
normed_x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val  = 
        train_test_split(normed_x_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=1)
```

Furthermore I have set both global and operation seeds:

```
tf.random.set_seed(42)
np.random.seed(24)
```

Now I define the model and set the weights in the most stupid way

```
a,b = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0].shape
weights = [np.ones((a,b)), np.zeros(model.layers[0].get_weights()[1].shape)]
model.layers[0].set_weights(weights)
```

This, for all the layers that I have

Then I run my `model.fit` function:

```
model.fit(normed_x_train, y_train, epochs=1,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val), verbose=1)
```

Then, I look at my weights

```
model.layers[0].get_weights()
```

for each layer.

So, I delete the model, build a new one, and repeat the operation here reported, from setting the weights in such a way as the one described above. But when, after the 1-epoch training, I go to see the weights values, they are not the same as the first run.

Why is that?

EDIT: I noticed that re-running the code from the imports, it gives the same results in terms of weights. Thus, I tried after deleting the model in the code, to add again the setting of the seeds, and only then re-create the model. Now the weights are the same as the previous run. Any explanations ?

Here the whole code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import scipy
import scipy.io as sio
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from numpy import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from numpy.random import seed
tf.random.set_seed(42)
np.random.seed(24)

def norm(x):
    std = np.std(x,0)
    mean = np.mean(x,0)
    return (x - mean) / std

def build_model():
    model = keras.Sequential([
        layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=([normed_x_train.shape[1]])),
        layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu)
        ])
    return model


x = random.randint(1000, size=(500,4))
y = np.mean(x,axis = 1)
y = np.resize(y,(y.shape[0],1))

# This is just for shuffle the dataset
a = np.concatenate((x,y), axis=1)
np.random.shuffle(a)
a = np.hsplit(a, (4,4))
x = a[0]
y = a[2]

x = norm(x)
normed_x_train, normed_x_test, y_train, y_test = 
    train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)

normed_x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val  = 
    train_test_split(normed_x_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=1) 

del model

model = build_model()
model.summary()

model.layers[0].get_weights()
a,b = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0].shape
weights = [np.ones((a,b)), np.zeros(model.layers[0].get_weights()[1].shape)]
model.layers[0].set_weights(weights)
model.layers[0].get_weights()

model.layers[1].get_weights()
a,b = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0].shape
weights = [np.ones((a,b)), np.zeros(model.layers[1].get_weights()[1].shape)]
model.layers[1].set_weights(weights)
model.layers[1].get_weights()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'mean_squared_error'],
              experimental_run_tf_function=False)
history = model.fit(normed_x_train, y_train, epochs=1,
                    validation_data=(x_val, y_val), verbose=1)
model.layers[0].get_weights()
model.layers[1].get_weights()
```

I'm running it in Jupiter, so the first part is runned only the first time.
Hope this helps

Comment: can you share the whole code? What optimizer are you using?

Comment: I'll do the edit right now; using Adam